# epicstore_api using this country not changing according to the fetch_store_games() params

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

```
import epicstore_api
client = epicstore_api.EpicGamesStoreAPI()
search_results = client.fetch_store_games(keywords="Dead Island 2 Gold Edition", allow_countries="UK")
print(search_results)
```

I am getting data for only usa if i use allow_countries="UK" or something else its giving me the same result for default USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the official docs](https://epicstore-api.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#epicstore_api.api.EpicGamesStoreAPI.fetch_store_games)

```
client = epicstore_api.api.EpicGamesStoreAPI(locale='en-US', country='US', session=None)
```

country default value is 'US' so you will never see results for UK ,  when I set country to UK I get  500 http response : the server does not know how to handle this request hence UK is unkown as country code.

However 'GB' will do just fine.
So you could set you're client as follow and go from there

```
client = epicstore_api.EpicGamesStoreAPI( locale='en-GB',country='GB')
```

And magically allow_countries accepts UK as value

```
client.fetch_store_games(keywords="Dead Island 2 Gold Edition",allow_countries="UK")
```